# GoWipe gone wrong

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am TH 8 and practicing GoWipe. I've had a lot of success but sometimes things go very wrong. All of my wizards went into an area with tons of bombs and in one second all my wizards got destroyed. Without the wizards, the 3 pekkas and barbarian king just went around the outside of the base destroying the trash on the perimeter.

The base had a lot of sectioned off areas, and when the wall breakers destroyed one part, all the wizards went into it. This area had the bombs so that's how I lost all of them. Also the defending CC castle was full of archers and balloons but I took them out with poison spells.

What do you do if you loose all your wizards early on in the attack? Should you give up and save your remaining troops?

Is the solution to make sure there's two holes in the walls and spread the wizards out so they go into separate areas?

Answer (score 2):

Of coarse, the bombs are meant to do exactly that, and the GoWiPe is not invincible so you should expect it to fail sometimes.

You however need to make sure that you do not release all your wizards at once. If you have 20 wizards its good to release maybe 12 first, and if they get blown now you have back up. And if the attack does not look promising, well, you can quit and save 8 wizards, as compared to all 20 and a loss.

Regarding the perimeter trash issue, its also because you are releasing everything at once. Spread a few wiz around (giants or pekka or golem leading of coarse) and let them clean the perimeter. The next set of wiz will go for the inside defences because they are the closest.